# Echoing a varied amount of variables into a varied amount of table cells

Tags: php, html

```
    echo $s['name'] .": ". $result ."<br />\n";
```

That's my code echoing $sitename[*] : $result[*]
Currently there are 3 sites that it echos.
However I want it to echo it like so:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>$sitename[0]</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>$result[0]</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>$sitename[1]</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>$result[1]</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>$sitename[2]</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>$result[2]</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

And then automatically add additional rows when I add a $site[3] and $site[4]

I'm not sure if this makes sense, if not, let me know and I'll try to rephrase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you will echo out the  tags, then inside do a for loop for each site, echo out the rest of the values that way.[For Loop Information](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/forloop.php)

So for example...

```
echo "<table>";
for ( $counter = 0; $counter <= 2; $counter += 1) 
{
   echo "
   <tr>
   <td>" . $sitename[$counter] . "</td>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
   <td>" . $result[$counter] . "</td>
   </tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

You can also look up for each loops if you are not sure how many sites you are adding, and want to create dynamic content.

Answer (score 1):

Just to make it a little simpler, as IPX mentions you might want to use a for each.

IPX's Code using a Foreach:

```
echo "<table>";
foreach ( $sitename as $counter => $name) 
{
   echo "
   <tr>
   <td>" . $name . "</td>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
   <td>" . $result[$counter] . "</td>
   </tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Yes, it is basically the same thing, but I felt I should just put it out there.

Comment: Perfect approach as well, did not have time to flush out both, thanks!